# stacking a dataframe using multi column index

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with multi-column index. I am trying to stack the data in such a way that it should look like the "expected" dataframe.

I tried .stack method but it does not stack exactly the way shown in the second dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_excel(
    "https://testme162.s3.amazonaws.com/just_stack.xlsx", header=list(range(5))
)

expected = pd.read_excel(
    "https://testme162.s3.amazonaws.com/just_stack.xlsx", sheet_name="expected",
)
```

Here is an image with explanation of how the data will look like...

[image: original and expected dataframe]

As on 23 July, there were around 82 records found. 2 files were uploaded in 2 (s3) buckets. The total may or may not match (66 + 16 = 82). The bucket, filename and it's count needs to be stacked for each day. There is only 1 row for each day.

Comment: Can you show the sample data and expected output ? not by the link~

Comment: I see that the original one has 28 rows while the expected only has 10. Is the expected output just a sample of what's needed?

Comment: I am using aggregate function "sum" on count column after grouping by key (i.e. date), bucket and filename. These 4 columns are required (6 columns are optional).

Comment: Typo. I mean "I have used". It means combination of key + bucket + filename is unique.

Comment: If this is an output of elasticsearch query then there is an official module https://github.com/elastic/eland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem Setup

Basically you start with a DataFrame that was transposed and nested to fit all grouped rows in a single row, alongside totals and subtotals.

Your expected result is a reconstruction of the raw data and then aggregated in a different way.

### Solution

So I believe the "best practice" solution would be to break down this data to its raw data (filenames & doc_counts) and and work up from there.

```
### split df on columns by buckets, seting (key, bucket_key) as index
### concatenate on axis=0
df.set_index(df.columns[0], inplace=True)
clean_dfs = []
j_bucket1, j_bucket2 = 3, 15 # input the column indexes for each bucket
for df1 in (df.iloc[:, j_bucket1:j_bucket2], df.iloc[:, j_bucket2:]):
    df1.set_index(df1.columns[0], append=True, inplace=True) #include bucket to index
    df1 = df1.drop(df1.columns[0:3], axis=1) # drop subtotals hardcoded to df
    df1.columns = ['filename', 'mycount'] * 4 # rename columns, preparing for concatenation and stacking
    clean_dfs.append(df1)
out = pd.concat(clean_dfs).rename_axis(['key', 'bucket']) # remove extra levels in MultiIndex level names
out = out.stack().dropna().rename('value').to_frame().reset_index(-1, drop=False) # this is the stack you were refering in the question
# reset the index level containing value type (filename / doc_count) so it is out of the index for concatenation
# if you left it there then concat down below would duplicate key+bucket rows again
# now it is the first column in dataframe 'out', pass it to groupby
out = pd.concat([out1.rename(var)
    for var, out1 in out.groupby(out.columns[0]).value], axis=1
    ).reset_index()

print(out)
```

Output

```
               key        bucket                                           filename mycount
0   cwl-2020.07.22    tempexport                          email_newsletters_old.csv    7327
1   cwl-2020.07.22    tempexport                               kyc_match_api.csv.gz    2053
2   cwl-2020.07.18  eiva-temp-s3                           perconabackupncpr.tar.gz    2109
3   cwl-2020.07.23    tempexport                                             000.gz      66
4   cwl-2020.07.20    tempexport                                             000.gz      33
5   cwl-2020.07.20    tempexport                                     svc_dlr.csv.gz       1
6   cwl-2020.07.20    tempexport                               svc_receiving.csv.gz       1
7   cwl-2020.07.20    tempexport                                 svc_sending.csv.gz       1
8   cwl-2020.07.25      mmm_eiva  mmm_servers_backup/tomcat_233/schedule_backup/...      15
9   cwl-2020.07.22      mmm_eiva  mmm_servers_backup/tomcat_233/schedule_backup/...      15
10  cwl-2020.07.18      mmm_eiva  mmm_servers_backup/tomcat_233/schedule_backup/...      15
11  cwl-2020.07.23      mmm_eiva  mmm_servers_backup/tomcat_233/schedule_backup/...      16
12  cwl-2020.07.20      mmm_eiva  mmm_servers_backup/tomcat_233/schedule_backup/...      15
13  cwl-2020.07.20      mmm_eiva  mmm_servers_backup/app_db_198/db/email360_emai...       1
```

Now we have clean data to work with. Calculate subtotals for key and bucket and insert to DataFrame:

```
### calculate doc_count totals per bucket and keys
out.insert(loc=1, column='doc_count',
    value=out.groupby('key').mycount.transform('sum').astype(np.int))
out.insert(loc=3, column='b_doc_count',
    value=out.groupby(['key', 'bucket']).mycount.transform('sum').astype(np.int))

### sort to preference
out.sort_values(['mycount'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
out.sort_values(['b_doc_count'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
out.sort_values(['doc_count'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
print(out)
```

Output

```
               key  doc_count        bucket  b_doc_count                                           filename mycount
0   cwl-2020.07.22       9395    tempexport         9380                          email_newsletters_old.csv    7327
1   cwl-2020.07.22       9395    tempexport         9380                               kyc_match_api.csv.gz    2053
9   cwl-2020.07.22       9395      mmm_eiva           15  mmm_servers_backup/tomcat_233/schedule_backup/...      15
2   cwl-2020.07.18       2124  eiva-temp-s3         2109                           perconabackupncpr.tar.gz    2109
10  cwl-2020.07.18       2124      mmm_eiva           15  mmm_servers_backup/tomcat_233/schedule_backup/...      15
3   cwl-2020.07.23         82    tempexport           66                                             000.gz      66
11  cwl-2020.07.23         82      mmm_eiva           16  mmm_servers_backup/tomcat_233/schedule_backup/...      16
4   cwl-2020.07.20         52    tempexport           36                                             000.gz      33
5   cwl-2020.07.20         52    tempexport           36                                     svc_dlr.csv.gz       1
6   cwl-2020.07.20         52    tempexport           36                               svc_receiving.csv.gz       1
7   cwl-2020.07.20         52    tempexport           36                                 svc_sending.csv.gz       1
12  cwl-2020.07.20         52      mmm_eiva           16  mmm_servers_backup/tomcat_233/schedule_backup/...      15
13  cwl-2020.07.20         52      mmm_eiva           16  mmm_servers_backup/app_db_198/db/email360_emai...       1
8   cwl-2020.07.25         15      mmm_eiva           15  mmm_servers_backup/tomcat_233/schedule_backup/...      15
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I found is `to_flat_index()` then a list comprehension to further eliminate elements of the tuples that are not wanted.  This gives you close to what you are looking for.  I have deliberately included the column# in the column name so that it's simple to drop all of the spurious columns that are not in your *expected* output.  There is one more iteration to fix column names as you want - but this is not in source xls

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2.columns = df2.columns.to_flat_index()
df2.columns = [
    [str(i) + "." + e for e in t if not ("Unnamed" in e or e in ["buckets","3","4"])][0]  
    for i,t in enumerate(df2.columns)  ]
df2.drop(columns=df2.columns[10:])
```

Comment: The output is not anywhere close to the expected dataframe. The sum of mycount after grouping on key and bucket should match with b_doc_count.   expected.groupby(["key", "bucket", "b_doc_count"])["mycount"].sum()

Comment: `df.columns.to_frame()` is way to see what is in column index.  There is not data to be able to `stack()` back to what you want. No where is there any data to show that *cwl-2020.07.22* is made up of *tempexport*2 and mmm_eiva* can't reconstruct what is not there ....